# SFDX Snapshot - Unsupported snapshot signup request fields: Namespace

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, namespace, snapshot, pilot, force-org-create

How to create a scratch org from a snapshot with namespace? Any workaround or solution?

**Error**

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "name": "INVALID_INPUT",
  "message": "Unsupported snapshot signup request fields: Namespace.",
  "exitCode": 1,
  "commandName": "OrgCreateCommand",
  "stack": "INVALID_INPUT: Unsupported snapshot signup request fields: Namespace.\n    at HttpApi.getError (.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/jsforce/lib/http-api.js:250:13)\n    at .local/share/sfdx/node_modules/jsforce/lib/http-api.js:95:22\n    at tryCallOne (.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)\n    at .local/share/sfdx/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15\n    at flush (.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)\nOuter stack:\n    at Function.wrap (.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/@salesforce/core/lib/sfdxError.js:151:27)\n    at OrgCreateCommand.catch (.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/ToolbeltCommand.js:246:46)",
  "warnings": []
}
```

**project-scratch-def.json**

```
{
    "orgName": "MyOrgName",
    "namespace": "myNamespace",
    "snapshot": "mySnapshot"
}
```

I've created a snapshot from a scratch org with a namespace. So when trying to create a new scratch org from this snapshot, I expect to have the same namespace, but it doesn't work like that.

When removing the namespace or when adding the same namespace from the snapshot, the following error happens *Unsupported snapshot signup request fields: Namespace*.

When blanking out or sending null, it does create the scratch org, however with no namespace, and of course, nothing works as expected.

Comment: Just a heads-up, because Scratch Org Snapshots are not a public feature and in a limited pilot, expertise around here may be fairly limited. Is there a Chatter group for the pilot?

Comment: @DavidReed, fair point! Thanks for that! I just have joined the group "Pilot: Scratch Org Snapshots"! https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A00000020d5

Comment: If you do receive a solution there that's OK to share publicly, please post it as an answer!

Comment: I've confirmed that it's a known limitation of the pilot. So unfortunately at the moment, there is no workaround and it doesn't work.

Comment: That's a shame but glad to know the situation - want to post an answer with the details you received?

Comment: @DavidReed, the snapshot solution is really great! It simplifies a lot the development process, especially when you need to install packages. It's a shame it's not working yet, but I'm sure it will. All I've received was this "Just this "It's a known limitation of the pilot sadly."

Comment: Isn't the namespace already built into the snapshot hence can't be redefined here?

Comment: Hi @KeithC, yes it is and that's what I would expect. I mean, if you have a snapshot with the namespace "abc", then when creating the new scratch org from it, I would expect "abc" as well on this new scratch org. Could you please confirm that it's working now? Probably it has already been addressed by Salesforce. I haven't tested that since then. I believe and hope that this pilot has advanced a lot over the past year. If it's working, would you mind adding your input as an answer. Thanks

Comment: @PabloFischer Unfortunately looks like the scratch org namespace is still not being propagated.